# WPF Datagrid - How to avoid second level grouping when value is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I have a grid that supports two-level grouping, the grouping is based on multiple columns. In cases when the value is "null", how can I avoid the second level grouping.

DataTable - converted to CollectionView is the data source of the below DataGrid. The data table has multiple two columns, "Category" and "SubCategory" based on which two-level grouping should be done - primary and secondary respectively. However, the catch is that the "SubCategory" is not applicable in all cases and certain rows may only have the "Category" - In that case, I don't want the second group level header to show up at all - right now it shows up as an empty row with the "expander" toggle button.

The Data is flexible, if I have to make changes to the datatable - I can do so. Please suggest.

```
<DataGrid Name="gridResult" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" AlternationCount="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding }" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="False" Margin="2,10,2,2" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent" AllowDrop="False" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource SecondGroupContainerStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>


<Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" Background="#FFBDC8C9" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1">
                <Expander.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <!--</StackPanel>-->
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </Expander>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SecondGroupContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}" >
            <Expander x:Name="exp" IsExpanded="True" Background="#FFC2CBCC" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Margin="5 0 0 0">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </Expander>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ever think of treating the data like folders?  Concatenate the Category & the SubCategory like this: `Category + SubCategory == null ? string.Empty : "\\" + SubCategory`.  Don't know what you'd have to do with your DataGrid to make that work, though.

Comment: DataGrid.GroupStyleSelector

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyleselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DataGrid.GroupStyle  excepts a collection of GroupStyles ?